# Excel VBA MSSQL speed

Tags: sql-server, excel, vba

I use an Excel spread sheet to update an MSSQL database with 50,000+ records. I am finding it very slow to create the records one by one, but it does not appear any quicker if I nest the records to reduce the queries to the database. eg.
Single queries:

```
INSERT INTO sales.promotions (
    promotion_name,
    discount,
    start_date,
    expired_date
)
VALUES
    (
        '2019 Summer Promotion',
        0.15,
        '20190601',
        '20190901'
    )

INSERT INTO sales.promotions (
    promotion_name,
    discount,
    start_date,
    expired_date
)
VALUES
    (
        '2019 Fall Promotion',
        0.20,
        '20191001',
        '20191101'
    )

INSERT INTO sales.promotions (
    promotion_name,
    discount,
    start_date,
    expired_date
)
VALUES
    (
        '2019 Winter Promotion',
        0.25,
        '20191201',
        '20200101'
    )
...
```

Nested query:

```
INSERT INTO sales.promotions (
    promotion_name,
    discount,
    start_date,
    expired_date
)
VALUES
    (
        '2019 Summer Promotion',
        0.15,
        '20190601',
        '20190901'
    ),
    (
        '2019 Fall Promotion',
        0.20,
        '20191001',
        '20191101'
    ),
    (
        '2019 Winter Promotion',
        0.25,
        '20191201',
        '20200101'
    ),
```

...

The nested queries appear to take just as long. Is this expected behaviour? The actual queries above are examples I found online and not the actual query I use which has many more values.

Comment: Inserting your data RBAR (Row by Agonising Row) is most certainly going to be the slowest method. There can, however, be many other reasons for slowness. Too many indexes on the table, or an incorrect choice of which is the `CLUSTERED INDEX` could be a couple. A poorly written trigger on the table could easily kill performance. Considering, however, you've said that the queries above have nothing to do with your environment, then we can do little but guess here. Representative queries and the query plans (via Paste the Plan) will help us help you here.

Comment: I'd advise you not to use VBA for this kind of task. Use a proper programming language and insert records in bulk. It's virtually instant for 50k records.

Comment: Can you suggest a proper language that I can embed into Excel other than VBA?